# IF case in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, null

I am trying to put in Result column:

- `S` (when gen1 or/and gen2 agree with genc)
- `E` (when genc collunm contain `E` string) and
- `N` (when gen1 or/and gen2 don't agree with genc).

```
  gen1    gen2    genc      Result
   3n      2n      2n         S
   2n      4n      1n       #VALUE!
   5-n     4n    1-2n(E)      E
```

In `N` cases I get `#VALUE!`. This is my code:

```
=IF(gen1=genc;"S";IF(gen2=genc;"S";IF(FIND("E";genc);"E";"N")))
```

To apply in excel:

```
=IF(A2=C2;"S";IF(B2=C2;"S";IF(FIND("E";C2);"E";"N")))
```

Why do I get `#VALUE!` instead of `N` and what should I do to get `N`?

Comment: `FIND("E";C2)` doesn't return true or false. You'll want something like `FIND("E";C2)>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `FIND` is returning an error, and this is neither a `TRUE` or a `FALSE` value. Try using `ISERROR` around:

```
=IF(A2=C2;"S";IF(B2=C2;"S";IF(ISERROR(FIND("E";C2));"N";"E")))
```

And you could use an `OR` like this:

```
=IF(OR(A2=C2;B2=C2);"S";IF(ISERROR(FIND("E";C2));"N";"E"))
```